# How to create an image chosen from gallery to bald look android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

Hi I am working for parlour app where I need to make an hair look person chosen from gallery to edit picture to bald look in imageview. How to make a picture to bald look? I searched how to do. But couldn't.  Please guide me.
Thanks.